# React - Jest : No tests found, exiting with code 1

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-scripts

I switched from windows to a dual boot with ubuntu.
I kept all my React projects by specifying the projects folder location.

My project works fine, but not tests with jest / react-scripts.

When I run all my tests with "react-scripts test", tests run successfully.

But when I want to run a single test (by clicking on the green triangle on Webstorm), I got this error

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
No files found in /media/me/OSDisk/Users/me/Documents/projects/my-project.
```

got this in my package.json :

```
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/*.test.ts?(x)"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.tsx",
      "!src/stories/**/*.tsx"
    ]
  }
```

react: 17.0.2
react-dom: 17.0.2
react-scripts: 4.0.3

I'm wondering if it's due to my projects that are located on a Windows folder. Is there a workaround to run a single test ? Should I clone again all my projects ?